# How To Manipulate Individual Radio Button Based On Select Input

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to change individual radio buttons to be disabled, depending of the select input.

For example, if a user selects "teach" in the select input - then all the languages they are already "teaching" should be disabled in the radio buttons. if the user selects "learn" then all the languages they are already "learning" will be disabled. (So they can only pick new ones)

I will receive a list of all languages + users teaching and learning languages in a service. For now i have just created them as an array.

html

```
<form [formGroup]="addLanguageFormGroup">
    <mat-form-field class="">
        <mat-select placeholder="Type" class="full-width" formControlName="type">
            <mat-option value="teach">Teach / Native</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="learn">Learn</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <br>
    <label for="">Select a language</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group" formControlName="language" aria-label="language">
        <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language"> {{language}}
        </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>

</form>
```

ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  languages:any;
  addLanguageFormGroup: FormGroup
  teaching: any;
  learning: any;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.addLanguageFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      type: ['', Validators.required],
      language: ['', Validators.required],

    });


    setTimeout((res) => {
      this.languages = ["Language1", "Language2", "Language3", "Language4", "Language5"];

      this.teaching = ["Language1"];

      this.learning = ["Language3"]
    });

  }


}
```

Comment: what is the exact form of your data?

Comment: Exactly the way its presented in this example

Comment: Please stop asking people to update some external website to show you their answer. That isn't how Stack Overflow works. Code goes in your question and in the answers *on the site* not on external code-hosting platforms.

Comment: The person clearly did not see the stackblitz, they came up with a random solution that wasent apart of this specific problem. Then he attempted to spam solutions.... I kindly asked if he could update the stackblitz to verify his solution works. its not against the terms to add a jsfiddle or stackblitz reference in my question, so im not sure why its being removed. I added it for reference to help people understand my problem.

Comment: @KHAN It is a requirement that your questions contain everything *in the question* required to answer it. Your code cannot sit on an externally hosted website.

Comment: @meagar it does, my question itself is detailed. What are you implying that is missng. There is no harm in providing a jsfiddle or stackblitz to showcase the problem and thats what i did. Whats the difference removing it here and leaving it in all other questions on stackoverflow that have a jsfiddle or stackblitz. Please tell me when tis right to add a jsfiddle and not.

Comment: @KHAN It obviously doesn't, if the other user *had* to visit your stackblitz for the context necessary to answer your question.

Comment: @meagar Where is the evidence for that? All the code was here.. you can even check the stackblitz i provided. Again tell me whats missing and when we can and cannot provide a stackblitz? its unreasonable of you to argue now that using stackblitz to showcase is against the rules here, as i assume thts why youre removing it.

Comment: And how is this now off topic when its a valid question, that meets minimal, verifiable and complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having another go today, its much simpler than i imagined.

**Firstly**, mat-select has a change directive which we can get the value of the select input. https://material.angular.io/components/select/api

```
<mat-select (change)="changed($event)" placeholder="Type" class="full-width" formControlName="type">
```

After we get this value we can bind it to a type variable to use later in disabling certain radio buttons.

```
type: any;

changed(v) {
   this.type = v.value;
}
```

**Then**, we set a disabled directive in the mat-radio button to point to a function where we handle the disabling of individual radio buttons. This function takes in the current language of the radio button.

```
<mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language" [disabled]="isDisabled(language)"> {{language}}
</mat-radio-button>
```

**Finally**, we implement the isDisabled function to firstly identify the type (learn or teach). Then we check if the current language which is passed into the isDsiabled function is inside the learning language array or not. If it is we return true to disable it. We do the same process for teaching.

```
  isDisabled(c) {

    if(this.type === "learn")
    {
      if(this.learning.indexOf(c) > -1) 
      {
        return true;
      }
    }

     if(this.type === "teach")
    {
      if(this.teaching.indexOf(c) > -1) 
      {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
```

See the updated stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qcr3lv?file=app/app.component.ts